# Detecting when ConditionB occurs after ConditionA in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have a coding question that I was hoping that some of the more experienced folks here could help me with.

I am hoping to create the following results.  It is based on minute data.  I have a column for 'ConditionA' and 'ConditionB'.  I am trying to detect which times 'ConditionB' occurs after 'ConditionA'.  I need to have it reset at the end of each day.

```
DATETIME                    ConditionA      ConditionB      Detected

2017-10-31 15:55:00.000         0               0               0
2017-10-31 15:56:00.000         1               0               0
2017-10-31 15:57:00.000         1               0               0
2017-10-31 15:58:00.000         1               0               0
2017-10-31 15:59:00.000         0               0               0
2017-10-31 16:00:00.000         0               1               1
2017-10-31 16:01:00.000         0               1               0
2017-10-31 16:02:00.000         0               1               0
2017-10-31 16:03:00.000         0               0               0
2017-10-31 16:04:00.000         1               0               0
2017-10-31 16:05:00.000         1               0               0
2017-10-31 16:06:00.000         0               0               0
2017-10-31 16:07:00.000         0               0               0
2017-10-31 16:08:00.000         0               1               1
2017-10-31 16:09:00.000         0               1               0
2017-10-31 16:10:00.000         0               1               0
2017-10-31 16:11:00.000         0               0               0
2017-10-31 16:12:00.000         0               1               0
2017-10-31 16:13:00.000         0               1               0
2017-10-31 16:14:00.000         0               1               0
2017-10-31 16:15:00.000         0               0               0
2017-10-31 16:16:00.000         0               1               0
2017-10-31 16:17:00.000         0               0               0
2017-10-31 16:18:00.000         0               0               0
2017-10-31 16:19:00.000         1               0               0
2017-10-31 16:20:00.000         1               0               0
2017-10-31 16:21:00.000         1               0               0
2017-10-31 16:22:00.000         0               0               0
2017-10-31 16:23:00.000         0               0               0
2017-10-31 16:24:00.000         1               0               0
2017-10-31 16:25:00.000         0               1               1
2017-10-31 16:26:00.000         0               1               0
```

I have been working on this for a week and been spinning my wheels.  I have considered CTE's, While Loops but have been having trouble wrapping my mind around this. Would someone mind pointing me in the right direction as to what methodology would end up working?  If I knew that, I could give that a try and ask further questions if needed.

thank you,

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you just want to see where `B` is `1` and the preceding value is not `0`.  If so:

```
select t.*,
       (case when b = 1 and lag(b) over (order by datetime) = 0
             then 1 else 0
        end) as detected
from t;
```

Comment: Gordon yes thank you, your solution is part of what I am aiming for.  In order to be 'Detected' ConditionB must occur only after Condition A has occured.  I have edited my original post and created an new table with additional rows to illustrate what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Gordon,  your answer led me to the solution.  it should be as follows:

```
select t.*,
   (case when b = 1 and lag(b) over (order by datetime) = 0
         then 1 else 0
    end) as detected
from t
where not (a = 0 AND b = 0);
```

Removing the rows with both conditions having zeros via the where clause allowed it to work as desired.